# Bootstrap: invisible glyphicon with same width of normal glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

imagine i have the following dropdown menu in a navbar:

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-invisible"></span> Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span> Test 2 (Active)</a></li>
      </ul>
```

I want to mark the active item with a glyphicon. The non active item with "Test 1" should have the same indentation as the active item "Test 2". I tried to reach this goal by adding a non existing glyphicon. This was possible with Boostrap 3.0.3 but in the new version 3.1.0 this "trick" is not working anymore.

With ASCII and Bootstrap 3.0.3:

```
    [IMAGE] Test 1
            Test 2
```

With ASCII and Bootstrap 3.1.0:

```
    [IMAGE] Test 1
    Test 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like...

```
.glyphicon{
    min-width: 15px;    
}
```

[DEMO](http://bootply.com/110352)